# BGRA being read as RGBA

Tags: ios5, opengl-es, avcapturesession, rgba, core-video

I am using AVCapture foundation to retrieve images (from the iphone 4 front camera) through the delegate call back. I have specified BGRA as the format with the following:

```
self.theOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
```

where self.output is of type AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

And I can preview the image correctly.

1. I have been trying to find a simple way to test the individual pixels RGBs to try to understand better, holding a blue card for example over the camera but the numbers just fluctuate between 80-110, versus my expected 0,0,255 what gives?
2. When I hold a white card over the camera, I would expect 255 for each of RGB, yet I am getting close to 120 for all. It seems it is discounting all numbers by 50% on the white. Any reason? But when I let direct light shine unto camera, I get 255 for each of the RGB element.

I feel I am missing some elementary understanding here.

Comment: How did you specify the BGRA and how do you read back to the unsigned char? Some code would help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for asking the right question. I updated with code. I also must have been really tired yesterday, it looks like BGRA pixels are read correctly as B,G,R,A in that order in a unsigned char *pixel so B=Pixel[0], G=Pixel[1], etc.... I have been reading back the data through simple NSlog: NSLog(@"The pixel at row 0 and column 0 is: %i,%i,%i,%i\n",framePixels[0], framePixels[1],framePixels[2],framePixels[3]); Can you kindly look at the other 2 questions. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect 255 for each of RGB, yet I am getting close to 120 for all.

A camera will try to automatically adjust its exposure to get the best picture. In this case it's probably assuming that the average brightness of the image should be around 128, and it adjusts to obtain that value. The camera can't tell if the paper you're holding in front of it is white, black, or middle gray, so it assumes it must be middle gray.

Comment: A lot to learn here Mark. Thanks. So do the RGB values get adjusted down by the % of Luminosity? I feel I am missing some elementary understanding here. Can you also point me to a primer online. Thanks much.

Comment: Yes, I see this pretty clearly when I try to do luminance averaging of an image from the iOS camera. Under normal lighting conditions (not a sudden bright light or dark area), the average luminance from a frame read from the iOS camera is almost always 50%. They clearly adjust the exposure and gain to track around this set point, unless you explicitly lock it on a value from an area in an image.

Comment: Thanks Brad. This further clarifies it. I wish there was a simple online "RGB sliders + luminance" emulator that could always validate colors.